# como botar cor diferentes em um titulo com array jquery

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de botar cores diferentes em titulo com um array jQuery, Mais sem se aleatória, no caso são cores pré definidas Estou começando agora a programar, e gostaria da ajuda de vcs. desde já Obridago

e isso que eu quero fazer igual da foto abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce nao precisa de jquery para isso, somente css resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como HudsonPH falou o melhor seria utilizar o css como solução,
mas se você precisa manipular um array que você já conhece com jquery, tente o seguinte:

```js
var cores = ['red', 'yellow', 'gray', 'orange', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow']

AddColors(cores);

function AddColors(cores){
  jQuery.each( cores, function( i, val ) {
    $(".container").append("<div id='"+i+"'>Bla bla bla</div>");
    $( "#" + i ).css("color", val);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```